# Why does my trigger get fired before insert of a row, even though specified [AFTER] in trigger declaration?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

**Problem**: confused in output of SQL trigger (*code posted below*)

```
SQL> insert into STUDENT VALUES('NAME');

Output: 
<<Trigger Executed>>
1 row created.
```

I created a trigger and a table simple enough to understand for the sake of readability and understanding:

Executing program ON : *[ORACLE 10g SQL Command line]*

```
SQL:> start F:/FILE.SQL
```

*FILE.SQL* contains (below code):

```
set serveroutput ON;

-- <<DROPING ANY TABLE IF ALREADY EXIST>>
DROP TABLE STUDENT ;

CREATE TABLE STUDENT  
(
    sname varchar2(20) 
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYTRIGGER
AFTER INSERT ON STUDENT 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('<<Trigger Executed>> '); 
END;
/
insert into STUDENT values('Myname');
```

**Question**: as the trigger is executed immediately after a value is inserted. So, if I have understood the theory correctly, the output should be:

```
1 row created.
<<Trigger Executed.>>
```

and not

```
<<Trigger Executed.>>
1 row created.
```

and logically that is correct.

**Tried**: I tried both `BEFORE` and `AFTER` in the trigger declaration to get the desired output but getting same results every time.

I know how triggers work, I'm just confused with the order of execution.

Comment: The result of output of the execution is up to the server, everything happens in the server then it send the result of the execution to the client (on the I/U/D/S case.). Since the trigger is a server event it output the dbms_ouput before the server sends to the client how many rows was affected by your insert command, therefore the output you are seeing.

Comment: @JorgeCampos from one of the answers, I understood the execution sequence, the insert operation gets executed first then triggers and then at last SQL sends how many rows affected as you have mentioned in comment. thank yew so much for being helpful on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is

1. New row is inserted.
2. Trigger is fired and prints `"<<Trigger Executed.>>"`.
3. Command is terminated and `"1 row created"` is printed by SQL*Plus.

I.e., *"1 row created"* is printed after the row has been inserted AND the trigger has been run. If you want to see whether the row has been inserted when the trigger is fired, print the the student name instead. Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYTRIGGER
    AFTER INSERT ON STUDENT 
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line('<<Trigger executed, student = ' || :new.sname || ' >>');
END;
```

The output should now be

```
<<Trigger executed, student = Myname >>  
1 row created.
```

Comment: So is `1 row created` simple a message that has to do nothing with execution?

Comment: It is printed once all the operations have terminated (insert + trigger), not at the very time the row is inserted.

Comment: @APC, it is intended to be in the trigger.  Added the trigger header lines now.

Answer (score 4):

Whatever the trigger does happens in the window of the transaction. In fact triggers are atomic with the firing statement: that is, if any trigger fails the entire statement fails.

Whereas `1 row created.` is just the SQL*Plus message that the statement has completed. It can't be displayed until the atomic action has finished. That's why the output of your trigger precedes the SQL*Plus message

Comment: Awesome answer, deserves vote up for just "Whereas 1 row created. is just the SQL*Plus message".